# Access to an object of my SWT thread from my Swing thread

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, eclipse-plugin, swt-awt

So I have an SWT thread, an eclipse plugin that consists of a simple view `myView`, with a JPanel `myJPanel` and a JTree `myJTree` embedded into it. With a listener on the Swing thread, when the selection change on my JTree it refresh JPanel into the Swing thread.

Simplified code version of my `myView` :

```
 public class myView extends ViewPart {
  public java.awt.Frame myFrame;

     @Override
      public void createPartControl(Composite parent) { 
        Composite myComposite = new Composite(parent, SWT.EMBEDDED);
        myFrame = SWT_AWT.new_Frame(myComposite); 
        myFrame.add(myJPanel);
        myFrame.repaint();
        myFrame.revalidate();

        //same kind of code for Jtree -> myJTreeFrame 
    }
```

What I want to do is to refresh `myFrame` from the Swing thread, when the listener of `myJTree` has to refresh `myJPanel`

I thought about this :

```
public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e) {
// some code that refresh myJPanel       

Display.getDefault().asyncExec(
    new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
          try { 
            myView view = (viewMap4j)PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().showView( "pluginProject.myView");
          } catch (PartInitException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
          view.myFrame.repaint();
          view.myFrame.revalidate(); 
      }
    });     
}
```

But I get this error with librairies : *No exception of type PartInitException can be thrown; an exception type must be a subclass of Throwable*

**My question is** : How to access to an object from my SWT thread (here `myView`) in a Swing thread?
and any ideas to make it work in this specific example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick, it gave me access to `myView` where I could find `myFrame` to refresh it from the JTree listener  :

```
  PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay().asyncExec(
            new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                try {
                  myView view =null;
                  view = (myView)PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().showView("pluginProject.myView");
                  view.reloadMyFrame();
                } catch (CoreException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
                } 
              }
            });
```